# Import Gmail Contacts to Iphone application...?

Tags: iphone, ios, gmail, import-contacts

I'm new to the IOS development platform. I need to import the gmail contacts to my application. I'm facing various issues with GData and some frameworks. So, Can anyone provide the demo or reference for that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you get the soluion......

Answer (score 3):

First of all use Gdata Framework and download Gdata Library [from here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction). Now, if using gdata in your project will cause several errors then [study this](http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-static-library-for-specific-api/), it will help you lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with [GData](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction) and resolve any issues you might encounter.

When I tried doing something similar [How To Use Google APIs with iPhone SDK](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/) helped me a lot.